# Skybox not texturing

Tags: opengl, skybox

[image]I have looked for a solution for a little while now however I'm not sure if other people have encountered my same problem. I am trying to draw a skybox in a blank opengl window, I have camera controls and I can zoom out and see the skybox is there but not being textured correctly/ at all. I have used code from opengl and I have only tried to implement it into a class.

Skybox.h

```
#pragma once

#include "wrapper_glfw.h"
#include <vector>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "shader_m.h"
#include "camera.h"



class Skybox
{
public:
    Skybox();
    ~Skybox();
  
  void init(GLWrapper *glw);
  void makeSkybox();
  void drawSkybox(Camera camera, glm::mat4 projection);
  void setFaces(std::string skyboxPath);
  unsigned int loadCubemap();
 
    private:
    std::vector<std::string> faces
    {
        "../src/images/skybox/default/right.jpg",
        "../src/images/skybox/default/left.jpg",
        "../src/images/skybox/default/top.jpg",
        "../src/images/skybox/default/bottom.jpg",
        "../src/images/skybox/default/front.jpg",
        "../src/images/skybox/default/back.jpg"
    };
    
    unsigned int cubemapTexture;
    unsigned int skyboxVAO, skyboxVBO;
    GLuint skyboxShader;

    //skybox, model, view, projection
    GLuint skyboxID, modelID, viewID, projectionID;
;

};
```

Skybox.cpp

```
#include "skybox.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"


Skybox::Skybox() 
{
}
Skybox::~Skybox()
{
  glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &skyboxVAO);
  glDeleteBuffers(1, &skyboxVBO);
}

void Skybox::init(GLWrapper *glw)
{
  skyboxShader = glw->LoadShader("shaders/skyboxShader/skybox.vert", "shaders/skyboxShader/skybox.frag");
  skyboxID = glGetUniformLocation(skyboxShader, "skybox");
  projectionID = glGetUniformLocation(skyboxShader, "projection");
  viewID = glGetUniformLocation(skyboxShader, "view");
  glUseProgram(skyboxShader);
}

void Skybox::makeSkybox()
{

float skyboxVertices[] = {
    // positions          
    -5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,
    -5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,
     5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,
     5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,
    -5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,

    -5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f,
    -5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,
    -5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,
    -5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,
    -5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
    -5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f,

     5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,
     5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,
     5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,

    -5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f,
    -5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f,
    -5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f,

    -5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
    -5.0f,  5.0f,  5.0f,
    -5.0f,  5.0f, -5.0f,

    -5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,
    -5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,
     5.0f, -5.0f, -5.0f,
    -5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f,
     5.0f, -5.0f,  5.0f
}; 
  
  // skybox VAO
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &skyboxVAO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &skyboxVBO);
  glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, skyboxVBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxVertices), &skyboxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0); 
    
  cubemapTexture = loadCubemap();

  // glUniform1ui(skyboxID, 0);
  glGetError();
}

void Skybox::drawSkybox(Camera camera, glm::mat4 projection)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // draw skybox as last
  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  // change depth function so depth test passes when values are equal to depth buffer's content
 
  glUniformMatrix4fv(viewID, 1, GL_FALSE, &camera.getView()[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionID, 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[0][0]); 
 
  // skybox cube
  glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemapTexture);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // set depth function back to default
  glUniform1ui(skyboxID, cubemapTexture);
  glGetError();
}



unsigned int Skybox::loadCubemap()
{
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureID);

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char *data = stbi_load(faces[i].c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
        if (data)
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Cubemap texture failed to load at path: " << faces[i] << std::endl;
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return textureID;
}
```

skyboxShader.frag:

```
#version 410 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 TexCoords;

uniform samplerCube skybox;

void main()
{    
    FragColor = texture(skybox, TexCoords);
}
```

skyboxShader.vert:

```
#version 410 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

out vec3 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = aPos;
    vec4 pos = projection * view * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pos.xyww;
}
```

I am using an M2 Macbook and I do not have a shader class like I have seen a lot of people use, I implement my shaders the way my lecturer has done so. I hope I have provided enough and thank you in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: If you replace your fragment shader with something like `FragColor = vec4(abs(fract(TexCooords)), 1);`, what do you see? This can help us diagnose whether there's an issue with sampling the texture of if the cube itself is being drawn wrong somehow.

Comment: @DMGregory When I use that I get the same result. My skybox is almost black with circles I believe on each face, they are quite hard to see but I think they are there.

Comment: Can you show us a picture? It would be very strange for that code to show all black.

Comment: @DMGregory ofcourse! I will add it now

Answer (score 1):

There were two mistakes I made which led to my skybox not texturing properly:

1. `Init` function was never called.... I'm sorry
2. `glUseProgram(skyboxShader)` should have been called in `drawSkybox` i.e. calling in the display loop. Thank you to everyone who replied and to anyone who had a look, feel free to steal my code if it is of any use to anyone